# How to add image in Cloud Firestore and display it in app?

Tags: android, firebase

I've been working for a quiz apps and apply the Cloud Firestore to store my question.
My problem here is how to add image into Cloud Firestore so that I can retrieved and display the image as question to users.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYmdt.png)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing image in the Cloud Firestore as they are large in size . Instead store those images in the Firebase Cloud Storage and keep the uri in the particular question as a sub-field. So whenever you want to display the image based on the question you retrieve the uri from the sub-field of the question and then get the image from the Cloud Storage based on the  uri .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase cloud storage to upload images and add only the image url in firebase cloud store.
Look at this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start